# Get Error for multiple on join in linq query for c#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Specified query below shows error in compile time. it says The name `wfmilestoneprojectrel` is not in scope on the right side of `equals`.  Consider swapping the expressions on either side of `equals`.
How can i resolve this ?
please help...

```
var test = 
   (from wfmilestonedefinition in _context.WF_MILESTONE_DEFINITION
    join wfmilestoneprojectrel in _context.WF_MILESTONE_PROJECT_REL
        on wfmilestonedefinition.MILESTONE_ID equals wfmilestoneprojectrel.MILESTONE_ID
    join workflowrecord in _context.WORKFLOW_RECORD
        on wfmilestoneprojectrel.PROJECT_ID equals workflowrecord.PROJECT_ID
    join workflowmilestone in _context.WORKFLOW_MILESTONE
        on
        new
            {
                wfmilestoneprojectrel.MILESTONE_PROJECT_REL_ID,
                workflowrecord.WF_ID
            } equals
        new
            {
                MILESTONE_PROJECT_REL_ID = wfmilestoneprojectrel.MILESTONE_PROJECT_REL_ID,
                workflowmilestone.WF_ID
            }
    select workflowmilestone).ToList();
```

Related Sql query which works well are given below : 
    SELECT     dbo.WF_MILESTONE_DEFINITION.MILESTONE_ID,         dbo.WF_MILESTONE_DEFINITION.MILESTONE_NAME, dbo.WF_MILESTONE_PROJECT_REL.PROJECT_ID, 
                      dbo.WORKFLOW_RECORD.WF_ID, dbo.WORKFLOW_MILESTONE.MILESTONE_E_DATE
FROM         dbo.WF_MILESTONE_DEFINITION INNER JOIN
                      dbo.WF_MILESTONE_PROJECT_REL ON dbo.WF_MILESTONE_DEFINITION.MILESTONE_ID = dbo.WF_MILESTONE_PROJECT_REL.MILESTONE_ID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.WORKFLOW_RECORD ON dbo.WF_MILESTONE_PROJECT_REL.PROJECT_ID = dbo.WORKFLOW_RECORD.PROJECT_ID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.WORKFLOW_MILESTONE ON 
                      dbo.WF_MILESTONE_PROJECT_REL.MILESTONE_PROJECT_REL_ID = dbo.WF_MILESTONE_PROJECT_REL.MILESTONE_PROJECT_REL_ID AND 
                      dbo.WORKFLOW_RECORD.WF_ID = dbo.WORKFLOW_MILESTONE.WF_ID

Comment: Which part of this `Consider swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'` you don't understand? Did you try it?

Comment: yes i try it.. but don't work. I translated this query from sql. sql query works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Look at definition of Join method that will be called behind the scenes:

```
Join<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(IEnumerable<TOuter>, 
                                    IEnumerable<TInner>, 
                                    Expression<Func<TOuter, TKey>>, 
                                    Expression<Func<TInner, TKey>>, 
                                    Expression<Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult>>)
```

The reason why are you getting this error because in your second join clause variable wfmilestoneprojectrel is not available because to that delegate passed variable workflowmilestone (TInner):

```
    new 
    {
      //here is no varialbe with name wfmilestoneprojectrel
      MILESTONE_PROJECT_REL_ID = wfmilestoneprojectrel.MILESTONE_PROJECT_REL_ID,
      workflowmilestone.WF_ID
    }
```

Why not just write:

```
join workflowmilestone in _context.WORKFLOW_MILESTONE
    on workflowrecord.WF_ID equals workflowmilestone.WF_ID
```

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something..

Comment: And given that the OP is using `wfmilestoneprojectrel.MILESTONE_PROJECT_REL_ID` in both of the anonymous objects it looks to me like it could just be removed...

Comment: Thanks @Alexey  for your feedback but i need wfmilestoneprojectrel.MILESTONE_PROJECT_REL_ID in both site of on query because it filters some data as my desired output.please help if i want my way then how can i do this ? just look the sql query ten you can understand.